# Spring4 + Thymeleaf3 Form Validation : bean name #fields not available in templates

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I get the below error in my spring4 + thymeleaf3 application when I try to show validation errors in my form template.

```
 Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '#fields' available as request attribute
```

My form is as below.

```
<form th:action="@{/user/save}" method="post" th:object="${user}">

<ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
   <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
</ul>

<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Last Name">
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="${#fields.errors('firstName')}"></div>
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="${#fields.errors('lastName')}"></div>
    </div>
</div>...
```

The form is rendered well for the following get request mapping.

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public String create(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("user", new User());
    return VIEW_DIR.concat("form");
}
```

But it gives the above error when the form is submitted with some invalid fields to the following method.

```
 @PostMapping("/save")
public String save(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return VIEW_DIR.concat("form");
    }

    userService.save(user);
    return "redirect:list";
}
```

Can you please show me where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting wrong values for th:errors inside your form element div. th:errors should contain field name. Update your form with this:

```
    <div>
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Last Name">
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}"></div>
        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}"></div>
    </div>
```